# Changing Party Member Outfits in Mass Effect 2

Tags: mass-effect-2

So I just completed the mission: Stealing Memory as part of the Kasumi DLC. I was told that I had unlocked an alternate costume.

Where can I see the costumes and/or change it for my squadmates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be seen at your private terminal, under the squad info section.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change them before each mission.

**Spoiler:**

> Miranda alternate suit is sooo sexy :)

Comment: "Spoiler: Miranda's ... suit is ... sexy" LOL. As if every trailer and PR image Bioware released didn't play up her outfits already. Yeah, but thanks for the spoiler warning.  :)