# How to access squad members' additional outfits

Tags: mass-effect-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing Party Member Outfits in Mass Effect 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/changing-party-member-outfits-in-mass-effect-2)

I've unlocked outfits for Jacob and Miranda.  How do I access them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to unlock them by completing their Loyalty missions, after which you can select them with a new 'Cycle Appearance' button when forming your party before a mission

Answer (score 1):

In the party selection menu before each mission, you have the option to toggle their outfit.